# Low and high pass filtering the phase

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have [this, matrix of complex numbers](https://mega.nz/#!DsNBWAgI!vdvIF5fwprKieIu5LxCOG-i5Edl1mNKcnkRYS2prwgQ) which represents an image (output of simulation)
I want to filter the **phase** of this image using **low-pass and high-pass filters**,

**My code (Low-pass filter only):**

```
%% Calculate the phase
   field_phase = angle(field);

%% Low-pass filter
   % Gaussian filter
   fieldPhase_Filtered = imgaussfilt(field_phase, 2);
```

**The output:**

```
imagesc(fieldPhase_Filtered); colorbar;
```

**1) do my steps are correct or not?**

**2) do I need to perform Fourier transform before calculating the phase as [they did here](http://matlabgeeks.com/tips-tutorials/how-to-do-a-2-d-fourier-transform-in-matlab/)?**

**3) what if I have more than matrices, do i need to normalize them before calculate the phase and applying the filters?**

Answer (score 0):

If it is the fourier transform of an image, you can transform it back using ifft2.

```
imagesc(log(abs(fftshift(ifft2(fftshift(field))))))
```

This looks pretty, but I du not see how this image has a phase. The phases of a fourier transform you can find pretty easy using `angle`

```
imagesc(angle(field))
```

As you can see they are either pi, -pi or 0.

[edit]

I see you want to analyse data from a simulation of a laser passing through a fiber? Do you want to find the mode indices from your images or something else?
https://www.rp-photonics.com/lp_modes.html

Comment: could you please elaborate your answer more?, do you mean that the result of **angle()** with FT is better than **angle()** without FT? What about applying the filters? Do I need to perform FT again on the phase before using the filters? or my previous code is correct?

Comment: `angle` gives the angle of the complex number. In a fourier transform this is equal to the phase of the wave at that frequency. I don't understand what you mean by "`angle()` without FT". What is the meaning of the complex number? Why is it complex at all?

Comment: In regard to your previous question **"Do you want to find the mode indices from your images or something else?"**. No, I am not trying to find the modes indices, unfortunately I cannot share all the details here.

**I don't understand what you mean by "angle() without FT"**
I mean without performing fftshift(fft2(field)) before angle();
**With Fourier Transform (FT) becomes like this:**
field_ft = fftshift(fft2(field));
field_phase = angle (field_ft);

Comment: `angle` calculates the angle of a complex value. Just like `abs` calculates the modulus of a complex value. I have no idea what data you have or what it is you want.

Comment: thank you for your help, after calculating the phase which method can be used to find a distinct feature of the mode, for example in the question I have provided the transverse field of LP02 mode.